# Code in Seq.map not executed?

Tags: f#

I have the following code. And the code between `Seq.map` and `ignore` is not executed. The two `printfn` are not executed. Why?

I tried to debug it and set breakpoints on

1. `links` (it highlights the whole pipe),
2. `printfn "Downloading"`
3. `printfn "Downloaded"` in function `download`.

The execution will break on the first one but breakpoint 2, 3 will never be hit. (or be stepped into). Does F# optimized the `Seq.map` part since the result is ignored?

```
let download url =
    printfn "Downloaded"
    () // Will complete the function later.

let getLinks url =
    ....
    |> Seq.toList

let .....
    async {
        ......
        links = getLinks url // Tried to modify getLinks to return a list instead of seq
        ........
            links // execution hit this pipe (as a whole)
            |> Seq.map (fun l -> 
                printfn "Downloading" // execution never hit here, tried links as Seq or List
                download l) 
            |> ignore
```

**Update:**
I know `for in do` works. Why `Seq.map` doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried printing `links` - as `seq` is lazy, it is possible that the `seq` is stuck in getting created earlier - although without a runnable example, I am just guessing.

Comment: I can see the values using quick view of Visual studio after get links as list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As John said, `seq` is lazy, and because you never actually traverse the sequence (instead just discarding it via `ignore`), the code in the lambda you pass to `Seq.map` is never executed. If you change `ignore` to `Seq.iter ignore` you will traverse the sequence and see the output you desire. (Any function that necessarily traverses the sequence will work, e.g. `Seq.count |> ignore`.)

Comment: I've updated my question. I tried to add `|> Seq.toList` at the end of `getLinks`.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 : Your edit doesn't address the problem – you're still discarding the result of `Seq.map` instead of traversing it.

Comment: I thought `Seq.toList` will traverse it? In C# `.ToList()` is used for the purpose. Is it different in F#?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 : Yes, but you're not traversing the right sequence. :-] You're traversing the input of `Seq.map`, not the output. With your edit, changing `Seq.map` to `List.map` would achieve the desired result, since `list` is not lazy.

Comment: Got it. The `Seq.map` creates a new seq. I guess I should use `for` in this scenario so the code will look simpler.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 : Well if you don't actually want the output of `download` then using `Seq.map` was misguided in the first place – `Seq.iter` with `ignore` inside of the lambda would be appropriate.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 : Under the hood, `for` is identical to `Seq.iter`; which one you use is purely a matter of taste. Personally, I dislike using "imperative" constructs in F# and would strictly use `Seq.iter`, but I know many would do the opposite.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe we can think `for` is the syntactic sugar of `Seq.iter` so it's just a taste issue.